# C++ how to work with pointers to vector pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have this design:

```
vector<string*>* tmp = new vector<string*>;
```

how do i put elements into it?
I can not understand how I put in this vector a few strings.
I tried it

```
std::string srt = "abc";
tmp->push_back(srt);
```

but the compiler curses and the syntax is incorrect, I don't know how to do

Comment: Just use `vector<string>` directly

Comment: @Justin I do not understand how

Comment: You can push back pointers to strings. `tmp->push_back(&str);` But if you don't understand pointers, dynamic allocation and mechanisms behind it and the need to use shared pointeres here, nothing will save you.

Comment: You do not need both pointers there. `std::vector<std::string>` will do nicely to you, as it did to millions and millions happy customers before you.

Comment: @user9431986 *I do not understand how* -- What seems strange to me is why you would think `std::vector<std::string*>*` would be easier to use than simply have `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: just repeating others, but the fact that you want to push a `std::string srt = "abc";` into the vector is a clear indication that you dont need a single `*` in your code

Comment: You need a tutorial on pointers and collections.

Answer (score 3):

just dont get too pointer-ish (assuming this is a relatively simple program)

```
vector<string> tmp;
std::string srt = "abc";
tmp.push_back(srt);
```

certainly a vector of pointers to string is a a disaster waiting to happen . And probably you dont need a pointer to a vector either

Answer (score 2):

The syntax would be  `tmp->push_back(&srt);`

But it would be better to use `vector<string>` because the vector will take care of the pointers for you.

Prefer:

```
std::vector<std::string> tmp;
std::string srt{"abc"};
tmp.push_back(srt);
```

Comment: `tmp->push_back(&srt)` will compile, but it will throw a runtime error: Access Violation Error at least within Visual Studio.

Comment: @FrancisCugler It works without error for me on Visual Studio. How did you read the value? You can use `*((*tmp)[0])`.

Comment: @ Wally ah okay, I had forgotten about the `double indirection` on the actual pointer to `vector`...

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

> How to work with pointers to vector pointers?

Let's look at a basic example...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // has to be initialized since it is a pointer.
    // However, this will compile but will fail at runtime.
    std::vector<std::string*>* pvWords = nullptr;

    std::string word1 = "Hello";
    std::string word2 = "World";

    // Here you need the `operator->()` from the vector
    // and since it will store pointers to strings,
    // you can just pass in the address of...
    pvWords->push_back( &word1 ); 
    pvWords->push_back( &word2 );

    for ( auto& s : *pvWords )    // here we need to dereference pvWords
        std::cout << *s << ' ';   // and here we need to dereference s
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

*-Expected Output-*

```
Hello World
```

However, this will compile but fails at runtime and causes an access violation error within Visual Studio. This fails because once the `strings` pointers go out of scope they are destroyed and the memory that the `vector` or `vector*` is trying to reference is now invalid. You might be able to get past this by using dynamic memory, but even then it just makes the code more complicated and harder to manage and can lead to even more unseen errors.

If we fix the above to the following snippet, the code will then work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string*>* pvWords = new std::vector<std::string*>;
   
    std::string word1 = "Hello";
    std::string word2 = "World";

    pvWords->push_back( &word1 ); 
    pvWords->push_back( &word2 );

    for ( auto& s : (*pvWords) )
        std::cout << (*s) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    delete pvWords; // don't forget to cleanup dynamic memory.

    return 0;
}
```

This will work with dynamic memory and will provide the following output:

```
Hello World
```

However, to avoid all of these errors and complexity of the code simply just don't use any pointers, especially when working with `std::string`.

---

---

The first solution will work but can lead to problems if any of the pointers become invalid before they are used and is tricky to avoid the runtime errors.

There is no need to use pointers in this situation. You are not storing derived classes of a base class where you need inheritance nor polymorphism.

Due to the behavior of `std::vector` and `std::string` simply doing this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vWords;

    vWords.push_back( "Hello" );
    vWords.push_back( "World" );

    for ( auto& s : vWords )
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Will produce the same expected results without any dynamic memory allocation and memory cleanup, without any errors, and without any code complications since `std::vector` and `std::string` manages their own memory.

*-Output-*

```
Hello World
```

This version of the code is much easier to read, cleaner to work with and debug, easier for others to use and will do exactly what you would expect it to do. This solution is very simple, fast and efficient without all of the hassle.

Comment: pvWords is initialized to nullptr. You can't access it. The second code block doesn't compile. Leave off the `= nullptr`

Comment: @doug I had thought so, but for some reason or another if I don't initialize it, I'm getting compiler errors...

Comment: You have two programs. The first one doesn't compile if you leave off `= nullptr` but you left off semi-colons at the end of the "Hello" and "World" strings. And the second one doesn't compile as is, but if you remove `= nullptr` from the second one it will compile and run correctly.  The reason the first one compiles (aside from the semi's) but doesn't run is that it needs to be initialized with `new vewctor<string>();`, not a nullptr. If you do that it will also compile and run.

Comment: @doug, The missing semi-colons is a typo. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I assumed it was just a typo. It's a good idea to copy code back from stackoverflow and compile it to check for typos. I've found some on posts I've made and it helps others trying to duplicate problems. Especially for those new to C++. The language can be intimidating at times.

Comment: Looking cleaner> Now you just need to clean up this line in the third program snippet: `std::vector<std::string> vWords = nullptr;`  Change it to `std::vector<std::string> vWords`;

Comment: @doug Fixed, another copy and paste error... Yeah, when I originally posted the answer it was late at night and I missed a few of those copy and paste errors (typos)...

Answer (score 0):

Using a vector your way can, but shouldn't, be done absent a compelling reason and I'm unable to think of one.

`vector<string*>* tmp = new vector<string*>;`

This is how you have to do it:

```
using std::vector; using std::string; using std::cout;

int main()
{
    vector<string*>* tmp = new vector<string*>;
    string srt = "abc";
    (*tmp).push_back(&srt);
    cout << *(*tmp)[0] << endl;
    delete tmp;
}
```

Alternately, one could use the indirection operator `->` instead of `*`. They do the same thing but both look ugly in different places.

```
    tmp->push_back(&srt);
    cout << *tmp->operator[](0) << endl;
```

Let's examine what is happening with `*(*tmp)[0]`. `(*tmp)` is the vector pointed to by `tmp`. `(*tmp)[0]` is the contents of the first element in the vector which is a pointer to a string. `*(*tmp)[0]` is that string pointed to by the first element in the vector.

Aside from the somewhat obscure syntax, beware of strings pointed to by elements in the vector going out of scope which will create dangling pointers.

This is the canonical way to use containers to store strings.

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> tmp;
    string srt = "abc";
    tmp.push_back(srt);
    cout << tmp[0] << endl;
}
```